# Injecting key/value into HashMap

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to generate HashMap object that will have properties and values set from parsed text input. Working fine with simple assigned, but wanted to make it more clever and use inject.

```
def result = new HashMap();
def buildLog = """
    BuildDir: 
    MSBuildProjectFile:test.csproj
    TargetName: test
    Compile: 
    Reference: 
""".trim().readLines()*.trim()

buildLog.each { 
    def (k,v) = it.tokenize(':')
    result."${k.trim()}"=v?.trim()
}

println "\nResult:\n${result.collect { k,v -> "\t$k='$v'\n" }.join()}"
```

generates expected output:

```
Result:
    Reference='null'
    MSBuildProjectFile='test.csproj'
    BuildDir='null'
    TargetName='test'
    Compile='null'
```

after replacing the insides of .each { } closure with injection:

```
it.tokenize(':').inject({ key, value -> result."${key}" = value?.trim()})
```

the results generated are missing unset values

```
Result:
    MSBuildProjectFile='test.csproj'
    TargetName='test'
```

Am I doing something wrong, tried with inject ("", {...})  but it seems to push may keys into values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inject` is basically a *reduce*.  The reducing function takes two arguments, the result of the previous iteration or the initial value (e.g. the accumulator) and the next value from the sequence.  So it could be made to work, but since you only expect one sequence value, it just convolutes the code.

I do see a great use for collectEntries here, as it allows you to create a Map using either small key/values map, or lists of two elements. And the latter you have:

```
result = buildLog.collectEntries {
    it.split(":",2)*.trim()
}
```

should work for your code instead of buildLog.each